# Bootstrap 4 - How to achieve this layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm currently working on a website and I have come across with the following problem thinking the best practice to achieve the following layout using Bootstrap 4. (Wrapped in Red)

[image]

As you can see the first column is a col-md-7 and the other one is col-md-5. However, the first column includes an image and it has to touch the left corner of the page. However, the right column has to have the standard width and column size. To give you more insight following is what I'm trying to achieve.

```
[JS Fiddle][2]
```

[image]

Comment: Why worry with the structure and classes with Bootstrap these days?  I'd highly recommend looking into native browser capabilities using CSS grid instead.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: Good point Aaron.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that using `align-self-start` class?

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.image {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col image">
      Image
    </div>
    <div class="col align-self-start">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap the left image and the right column in a row, set the column width for each, then place each item in the right column inside of that div with a full width.

I think if you continue to ask "do it for me" questions on SO you will get roasted, I know I have. But I'm here to help. LMK if you want more details.

There are a million solutions to this problem, This would be a great time to look into CSS Grid and learn the new new.

[Here is a codepen of the general approach](https://codepen.io/williamholt0004/pen/VwLeqvg)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7 left-box"></div>

  <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="col-md-12 item"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 item"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 item"></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```